# Simulate data from a bivariate normal distribution (obtain some bimodal effect)

Tags: classification, normal-distribution, data-visualization

I playing around trying to emulate  a visualization of  the book *[Introduction to Statistical Learning, chapter 2, page 38](http://faculty.marshall.usc.edu/gareth-james/ISL/ISLR%20Seventh%20Printing.pdf)*.

My problem is that I cannot achieve to draw a decision boundary of a similar shape. I generated the data from two bivariate normal distributions and I obtained only a decision boundaries with parabolic shapes (using a naive bayes classifier).

Then I pick the blue class from a mix of two bivariates normal distribution trying to generate some bimodal effect and obtain a more polynomial decision boundary but the plan didn't work.

[image]

Here is the visual way that I trying to tune the parameters to generate points. The blue are the two bivariate normal-distributions that I said before to generate 50 points from each other.

**Someone who knows a way to generate data from a distribution to have control of the parameters and obtain a similar decision boundary as the first plot?**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for showing the reference: You might use the following method to get a bivariate distribution with specified correlation: Suppose $X$ and $Z$ are independently distributed as $\mathsf{Norm}(0,1)$ and $-1 <\rho <1.$
Let $Y = X\rho + Z\sqrt{1-\rho^2}.$ Then $\mathrm{Cor}(X,Y) = \rho.$ // Then make each of the bi-modal distributions by sampling 50:50 from two suitably-centered bivariate normal distributions.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/81197/can-someone-please-explain-to-me-what-the-particular-scenarios-mean/81952#81952.  For details, [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=gauss*+mixture+generate+score%3A1+-means).